# Evaluating the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{n}{n/2}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n(2a)^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form

I encountered the following series while evaluating an integral

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{n}{n/2}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n(2a)^n}, \quad a\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

and am looking for a closed form. I have looked up generating functions and found some close candidates such as,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^n}{4^nn}
= 2\log\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)
\end{equation}

but I can't figure out how to deal with the $\binom{n}{n/2}$ term. Looking at the power series for $(1+x)^n$, I assume finding such a function may be difficult, but I hope a closed form exists.

I will be happy to add my evaluation of the original integral up to the point where the series appears, if that may be necessary.

Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit:**

Here is the integral I was evaluating,
$$J(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(1+\frac{\sin x}{a}\right)\ dx,\quad a\in\mathbb{R}$$
which comes from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4744617/1141581) post, and the derivations of the series are in my answer there. I hope this helps @ClaudeLeibovici.

Comment: The terms in your sum are only defined for even $n$. What do you intend for the binomial coefficient for odd $n$, perhaps rounding down: $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$?

Comment: @SammyBlack. Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought the binomial coefficient, $$\binom{n}{n/2}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n/2+1)\Gamma(n-n/2+1)}$$
will be defined for odd $n$, as positive half integer arguments of the Gamma function have an exact formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function),
$$\Gamma(n/2)=\frac{\sqrt\pi(n-2)!!}{2^{(n-1)/2}}.$$

Comment: If $n=2k-1$,$$\binom n{\frac n2}=\binom{2k-1}{k-\frac12}=\frac{2^{4k}}\pi \frac{(2k-1)! (k!)^2 }{\left((2k)!\right)^2}=\frac{2^{4k-1}}{\pi k \binom{2k}k}$$which is closely related to the derivative of $\arcsin^2x$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448822/taylor-expansion-for-arcsin2x)

Comment: $$S_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{x^n}{n^k}$$ is the sum of two hypergeometric functions (at least for integer values of $k$). $k=1$ is a particular case.

Comment: Could you post the integral ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Done! Cheers:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=-\frac 1 {2a}$ and consider
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{x^n}{n} $$
$$S'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x \sqrt{1-4 x^2}}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2 \sin ^{-1}(2 x)}{\pi  x
   \sqrt{1-4 x^2}}$$ Integrating (do not forget the integration constant which is $\log(2)$)
$$S(x)=\log \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}{2 x^2}\right)+\frac 2 \pi \int \frac{\sin ^{-1}(2 x)}{ x \sqrt{1-4 x^2}}\,dx$$
Now, the problem is
$$I=\int \frac{\sin ^{-1}(2 x)}{ x \sqrt{1-4 x^2}}\,dx$$
Integrating by parts
$$I=-\sin ^{-1}(2 x) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-4 x^2}\right)+2\int \frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-4 x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}\,dx$$
$$J=\int \frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-4 x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}\,dx$$ Using $t=\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-4 x^2}\right)$
$$J=-i\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}\left(t\, \log \left(\frac{e^t-i}{e^t+i}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-i e^{-t}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(i e^{-t}\right)     \right)$$

**Edit**

From a formal point of view, the best expression is
$$S(x)=\log \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}{2 x^2}\right)+\frac {4x} \pi  \,\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};4 x^2\right)$$ which has been obtained separating the odd and even terms.

So, the sum is title is
$$\large\color{blue}{\log \left(2 a \left(a-\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)\right)-\frac{2}{a\pi  }\,\,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{a^2}\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help as always Claude :)

Comment: @bob. I am always glad to help and to share the little I know with others. Cheers :-)

Comment: I am getting a weird results when numerically evaluating the sum. With $x=-1/10$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{n}{n/2}\frac{x^n}{n}\approx-0.11832457681$$
while,
$$-\log\left(1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}\right)+\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^x\frac{\arcsin(2t)}{t\sqrt{1-4t^2}}\ dt\approx−0.81147175737$$
can you help me fix this issue?

Comment: @bob. I shall look AT tomorrow early morning (almost dinner Time hère).

Comment: Sounds good. I will also check back tomorrow morning (almost bed time here).

Comment: @bob. I forgot the integration constant which is $\log(2)$. If you check your numbers $$−0.11832457681+0.81147175737=0.69314718056=\log(2)$$

Comment: @bob. In terms of $x$, the function is much nicer than in terms of $a$. Plot the two functions.

Comment: I just got back, thank you for the edits and help. I should've seen the $\log(2)$ term missing. About the two functions (in terms of $x$ and $a$), do you reckon you can add the plots as graphics? You have already done so much, once again thank you.

Comment: @bob. Being blind, I am unable to produce decent plots. I think that it could be a good idea you add them in your post. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the binomial coefficients by gamma functions,
making the problem more general, at least for positive integer values of $k$, $$S_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{x^n}{n^k}$$ write as the sum of two hypergeometric functions
$$\color{blue}{S_2(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}  \, _4F_3\left(1,1,1,\frac{3}{2};2,2,2;4
   x^2\right)+}$$ $$\color{blue}{\frac {4x}\pi \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2
   },\frac{3}{2};4 x^2\right)}$$
$$S_3(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}  \, _5F_4\left(1,1,1,1,\frac{3}{2};2,2,2,2;4
   x^2\right)+$$
$$\frac {4x}\pi \,
   _5F_4\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2
   },\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};4 x^2\right)$$
$$\color{blue}{S_4(x)=\frac{x^2}{8} \, _6F_5\left(1,1,1,1,1,\frac{3}{2};2,2,2,2,2;4 x^2\right)+}$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac {4x}\pi \,
   _6F_5\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,
   1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}
   ;4 x^2\right)}$$ and we probably could conjecture what is
$S_k(x)$ looking at the very simple patterns.

Comment: Do you believe this is worth conjecturing?

Comment: @bob. Yes, I think

Comment: Ok that is exciting. However, I have little experience with the Hypergeometric function so I do not know what exactly to conjecture. Is it possible that you write the conjecturing post? If not, I am happy to do so as long as I have time to do a little more research.